# Basic под Windows 7

Tags: ide, ссылки

Где скачать обычный Basic, совместимый с Windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

`Visual Studio` уже не подходит? Из множества шаблонов, насколько я помню есть и необходимый вам бейсик.

[скачать](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/ru-ru/products/2010-editions/express)

Comment: Visual Studio подходит, только мне нужен простой basic, для того чтобы познакомиться с языком.

Comment: Может мне начать с турбо паскаль?

Comment: если знакомиться с языком, всё равно нужна среда для разработки... а vs самая распространённая среда, в принципе вот и всё) качай книги по бесику и вс, но советую хотябы PRO версию)

Answer (score 0):

я с Visual Studio 2003 начинал. Там кроме basic'а, есть ещё C# и, по-моему, C++.